# A subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ invariant under an involution

Tags: commutative-algebra, extension-field, birational-geometry, involutions

Let $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Let $\beta: \mathbb{C}[x,y] \to \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ be the involution (= $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphism of order two) defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$.

Denote the symmetric elements with respect to $\beta$ by $S_{\beta}$ and the skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\beta$ by $K_{\beta}$.

Assume that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is invariant under $\beta$, namely, $\beta(u) \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$ and $\beta(v) \in \mathbb{C}(u,v)$.

> Is it true that the following property P is satisfied: There exists an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that 
>   $g(u),g(v) \in S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$?

**Example:** $u=x+y^2$, $v=x+y+y^2$. It is easy to see that $\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(x,y)$ which is $\beta$-invariant. $u \in S_{\beta} \subset S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$, $v \notin S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$. However, there exists an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ for which $g(u),g(v) \in S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$: $g: (x,y) \mapsto (x-(y-x)^2,y-x)$. Indeed, $g(u)=g(x+y^2)=g(x)+g(y)^2=x-(y-x)^2+(y-x)^2=x \in S_{\beta}$ and $g(v)=g(x+y+y^2)=g(u+y)=g(u)+g(y)=x+(y-x)=y \in K_{\beta}$.

**More generally:** If $h: (x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]=\mathbb{C}[u,v]$, so $\mathbb{C}(x,y)=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is $\beta$-invariant, and taking $g:=h^{-1}$ we obtain $g(u)=h^{-1}(u)=h^{-1}(h(x))=x \in S_{\beta}$ and $g(v)=h^{-1}(v)=h^{-1}(h(y))=y \in K_{\beta}$.

Therefore, **a partial answer is**: If $(x,y) \mapsto (u,v)$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, then property P is satisfied.

**Remark:** 
If I am not wrong,
$\mathbb{C}(u,v)=\mathbb{C}(s_1,k_1,s_2,k_2)$, where $u=s_1+k_1, v=s_2+k_2, s_i \in S_{\beta}, k_i \in K_{\beta}$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.

Any comments and hints are welcome!

Now asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354155/characterizing-subfields-mathbbcu-v-subseteq-mathbbcx-y-invariant-u).

Comment: In your remark, should the round brackets in the sentence beginning "Clearly" be square brackets? And why doesn't your choice of $u$ and $v$ work for both the polynomial rings and the power series rings?

Comment: Yes, thanks, this is what I really wanted to write.

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer then. And why do you think you argument doesn't work for the power series rings too? It looks good to me.

Comment: ok, I have edited now. You are right, I will think about my question again. (By $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ I meant the field of fractions of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$).

Comment: I really apologize, I was confused, and now I have edited my question to what I wanted to ask.

Comment: No need to apologize. It was my misunderstanding about your notation. But with $u$ and $v$ as you propose, you have $y = v - u$ and $x = v - (v - u)^2$, so $\Bbb{C}(u, v) = \Bbb{C}(x, y)$, which is invariant under $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the old version of my question has a negative answer, as you mention. Please, any ideas about the new version of my question?

Comment: Take $u = x$, $v = y$ and $g$ to be the identity automorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: This is the kind of misunderstanding that happens if you try to make a radical change to a question that is under discussion. I think you are now saying that $u$ and $v$ are given such that $\Bbb{C}(u, v)$ is invariant. Before your edit, you were asking about the existence of $u$ and $v$ with a certain property.

Comment: I really apologize for the $\infty$ edits (it is probably difficult to follow what I meant, sorry). Before and after the edit $\mathbb{C}(u,v)$ is $\beta$-invariant. The change is in the property: The property before editting: $u,v \in S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$ (which is not true, as $u=x+y^2,v=x+y+y^2$ shows, since $v$ is not symmetric or skew-symmetric), after the edit the property: There exists an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ such that $g(u),g(v) \in S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$.